# Really basic SSE

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, sse, sse3

I have a very simple program that I am trying to improve performance. One way that I know will help is to utilize SSE3 (since the machine that I am working supports this), but I have absolutely no idea how to to do this. Here is a code snippet (c++):

```
int sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4;
for (int i=0; i<length; i+=4) {
  for (int j=0; j<length; j+=4) {
    sum1 = sum1 + input->value[i][j];
    sum2 = sum2 + input->value[i+1][j+1];
    sum3 = sum3 + input->value[i+2][j+3];
    sum4 = sum4 + input->value[i+3][j+4];    
  {
}
```

I've read a little about this, and understand the idea, but I have absolutely no idea how to implement this. Can somebody help me please? I think that this is fairly simple, particularly for my simple program, but sometimes getting started is the hardest part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, in your case, it is not that simple. As it stands right now, your code is ***NOT*** vectorizable. (at least not without significant loop transformations)

The reason for this is that you are changing the index `i` as well inside the inner loop. The breaks any chance of being able to vectorize the `j` iteration because the memory locations are no longer adjacent and are in different rows of the matrix. (as you seem to be running down the matrix diagonally)

However, I get the feeling that you are trying to sum up all the elements in your matrix, and you actually intended your loop to be like this (and you had a number of typos too):

```
int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0, sum4 = 0;
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<length; j+=4) {
    sum1 = sum1 + input->value[i][j];
    sum2 = sum2 + input->value[i][j+1];
    sum3 = sum3 + input->value[i][j+2];
    sum4 = sum4 + input->value[i][j+3];    
  }
}

int total = sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4;
```

If this is what you wanted, then it is very vectorizable.
In C/C++ using intrinsics, this can be done as follows using just SSE2:

```
__m128i sum = _mm_setzero_si128();
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<length; j+=4) {
    __m128i val = _mm_load_si128(&input->value[i][j]);
    sum = _mm_add_epi32(sum,val);
  }
}
```

Note that alignment restrictions will apply. And a lot more speedup can be gained by further unrolling the loop.